# Why doesn't my group have a sprite attribute?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to loop through the sprites in my group so I can draw them. However, I get a message that the group doesn't have a sprite attribute.

I have tried to declare the group and sprite in the function module (where I am getting the error) as opposed to the main module. That doesn't work. I tried to do it without the sprite attribute. That doesn't work.

```
   #Assign bullets sprite a value
   bullet = Bullet(screen, ship)
   #assign a group for bullets
   pewpew = Group()
```

Here is the bullet class:

```
  import pygame
  from pygame.sprite import Sprite

  class Bullet():

      def __init__(self, screen, ship):
          """initiate the bullet sprite"""
          super(Bullet, self).__init__()
          self.screen = screen

          #Places everyone, places
          self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 3, 15)
          self.rect.centery = ship.rect.centery
          self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

          #Decimal and delightful colors!
          self.x = float(self.rect.x)
          self.color = 60, 60, 60

        def update(self):
         #almost faster than superman
          self.x =+ 5
          self.rect.x = self.x

         def draw_bullet(self):
          """Animate"""
           pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Here is where the error occurs:

```
   def screenupdate(screen, rct, ship, bullet, pewpew):
         """Update screen images and flip to a new screen"""
         #Redraw screen for everytime the function loops
         screen.fill((230, 230, 230))
         #Redraw the bullets
         for bullet in pewpew.sprite():
             bullet.draw_bullet()
         ship.blitme()
         #rectangle.draw(screen)

         #Make the screen visible
         pygame.display.flip()
```

Instead of looping, I get the message:
"for bullet in pewpew.sprite():
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'sprite'"

Comment: check documentation - [Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) doesn't have `sprite()` but `sprites()` with char `s` at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I should have figured I would type it wrong. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how Sprites and Groups are supposed to work. If you just want to loop over a collection and do all the drawing yourself (without any of the features the `Group` provides), use a simple list (`[]`).

If you want to actually make use of the Group class, ensure that the `Bullet` is actually a `Sprite`:

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ship, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((3, 15))
        self.image.fill((60, 60, 60))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centery = ship.rect.centery
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip((5, 0))
```

then create the Group / Bullet:

```
pewpew = Group()     # create the Group
Bullet(ship, pewpew) # create the Bullet
```

and in your mainloop, simply call `update` and `draw` on the group instance:

```
def screenupdate(screen, rct, ship, bullet, pewpew):
     """Update screen images and flip to a new screen"""
     #Redraw screen for everytime the function loops
     screen.fill((230, 230, 230))

     pewpew.update()
     pewpew.draw(screen)         

     ship.blitme()

     pygame.display.flip()
```

Now make sure that `ship` is also a `Sprite` and add it to the `pewpew` Group so you can get rid of the `ship.blitme()`-function, too.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I could do it as a list. There is definitely more than one way to get home.